# Why will it crash when optimization level is for speed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I use `cocoapods` manager my libs. One of my private lib called `ZXZ` which also depend on `RxSwift` 、 `RxCocoa`. If I use `ZXZ` by source code it will run well. But if I make `ZXZ` to a framework, and use it in my project. It will crash.

The error messages like below:

```
MyProject(777,0x1b3983b40) malloc: *** error for object 0x1706cbb40: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Finally I found if this framework optimization level is `optimize for speed` my project will crash.

But before I making it to a framework, I set `ZXZ` optimization level to `No optimization` my project will be ok.

How can I solve it?

Comment: That looks like a bug in your framework. Do what Xcode suggests. Enabling the Address Sanitizer might also help to isolate the problem.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a memory management bug in or near your ZXZ code. Probably something you're happening to get away with until a more aggressive optimizer gets involved. I would first study and code you have marked Unsafe, or any ObjC code, or anywhere you access variables on a dispatch queue. "Unsafe" code in particular is very easy to use incorrectly in ways that work fine in Debug, but cause problems in Release (and sometimes problems in code completely unrelated to the actual cause). If possible, split up ZXZ and try making part of it a framework to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. This because I made `ZXZ` in release mode. But I build my project in debug mode. My framework also depend on `RxSwift` which doesn't make into framework. `RxSwift` has some code likes below:

```
#if DEBUG
    import class Foundation.Thread
    final class SynchronizationTracker {
        private let _lock = RecursiveLock()
```

So it crash. Some resolved methods can reference [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1972)